# TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined - App.componentWillMount

Tags: javascript

I am making an app in javascript with firebase. The problem is with the property "on". I cant seem to fix it. The problem in line 31. -->> this.database.on('child_added', snap => {
The error is -->> TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined.
Any help is appreciated! Explanation would be nice too.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Card from './Card/Card'
import DrawButton from './DrawButton/DrawButton';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';

import { DB_CONFIG } from './Config/Firebase/db_config';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);
    this.database = firebase.database().ref().child('cards');
    }

    this.updateCard = this.updateCard.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      cards: [],
      currentCard: {}
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    const currentCards = this.state.cards;
    this.database.on('child_added', snap => {
      currentCards.push({
        id: snap.key,
        ques: snap.val().ques,
        ans: snap.val().ans,
      })
      this.setState({
        cards: currentCards,
        currentCard: this.getRandomCard(currentCards)
      })
    })
  }
  getRandomCard(currentCards){
    var card = currentCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * currentCards.length)];
    return(card);
  }

  updateCard(){
    const currentCards = this.state.cards;
    this.setState({
      currentCard: this.getRandomCard(currentCards)
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="cardRow">
          <Card ques={this.state.currentCard.ques} 
                ans={this.state.currentCard.ans} 
          />
        </div>
        <div className="buttonRow">
          <DrawButton drawCard={this.updateCard}/>
        </div>   
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.database` does not get assigned and is `undefined` since `!firebase.apps.length` returns `false` which probably means the Firebase app is initialized somewhere else. You should move the `this.database` assignment outside the `if` condition.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG)
  }

  this.database = firebase.database().ref().child('cards')

  //...
}
```

I would recommend using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook to fetch data. Check [this](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/) article for more information.